# Can Tasks suffer from slow scheduling, even though ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads() indicates abundance?

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

We have a server running in production, that receives data, puts in into `queueA`. Another thread takes one item at a time from `queueA`, processes it and puts it into `queueB`.

This setup is actually mirrored so that both of the mirrored servers receive the exact same data and process them in the same way, in an active-active redundancy setup.

About once a year, messages of one of the servers pile up massively in `queueA`, whereas the other server handles the same data just fine.

So the problem seems to be the code that takes from `queueA`, processes, and enqueues into `queueB`. There is not much going on there, except (completely unnecessary) use of the Task library as shown in the stripped down and simplified version below.

```
public IAsyncResult BeginReceive()
{
  Task<object> task = new Task<object>(_ =>
  {
    object message;
    if (!queueA.TryDequeue(out message))
    {
      if (queueA.IsEmpty)
        waitQueueA.WaitOne(10); // waitQueueA is properly signaled whenever an item is put into queueA
    }
    return message;
  }, null, TaskCreationOptions.PreferFairness);

  task.ContinueWith((t) =>
  {
    object receivedMessage = t.Result;
    if (receivedMessage != null)
    {
      lock (bLock) // bLock is only used by this piece of code
      {
        queueB.Enqueue(receivedMessage);
      }
    }
    else
    {
      Thread.Sleep(1);
    }
    BeginReceive(OnReceive, channel);
  });

  task.Start();
  return task;
}

public object EndReceive(IAsyncResult result)
{
  Task<object> task = (Task<object>) result;
  return task.Result;
}
```

Ignoring the many idiosyncrasies of the code (personally, I would have created a single, dedicated thread for this and performed all the above in one big `while (true) { }` loop, without any `Task`s involved), which circumstances could make it perform so poorly, that the loop spins at a performance of mostly 15 iterations/sec, maxing out at under 50 iterations/sec? We log `ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads()` every 5 seconds, and it indicates thousands of available threads throughout.

This codes runs fine (enough) most of the time, but when it fails, it seems to fail right from the start of the program until its end, which is in the range of an hour or so, when memory is exhausted by `queueA` and its items. So it looks like the program can be brought into some funky state from which it will not recover.

Here's a chart of the number of items processed per second, for the good machine and the bad machine, the horizontal axis is the time axis. (Please note the vertical axis is logarithmic)

[image]

The chart shows e.g. that the "bad" server has a ceiling of about 17/18 items/sec, most of the time, whereas the the "good" server is able to do 3700 items/sec, depending on the rate that new items are received and enter `queueA`.

As I'm not too familiar with the intricacies of the task library, I wonder if perhaps the combination of `PreferFairness` and the asynchronous (and hence not really) "recursive" call of `BeginReceive` could cause this issue, under some random circumstances. Any other idea how to get to the bottom of this?

N.B. I have removed a couple of `try {} catch { error.log(); }` constructs to simplify it. There are no errors logged, so I'm confident the code does not throw exceptions. And the `queueA` does not monotonously grow, it sometimes shrinks a tiny bit, so that loop seems to be alive, albeit slow.

Comment: Answering myself: It [seems](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/taskcreationoptions-preferfairness/), `PreferFairness` would, if anything, make things better, because the new task will not end up in a local queue. But reading that blog post it seems more likely that flag would not be related to my problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/taskcreationoptions-preferfairness/) is a very good reading on the subject.

> When a Task is scheduled to the default scheduler, the scheduler looks
>   to see whether the current thread from which the Task is being queued
>   is a ThreadPool thread that has its own local queue.  If it isn’t, the
>   work item will be queued to the global queue.  If it is, the scheduler
>   will also check whether the TaskCreationOptions value for the Task
>   includes the PreferFairness flag, which is not on by default.  If the
>   flag is set, even if the thread does have its own local queue, the
>   scheduler will still enqueue the Task to the global queue rather than
>   to the local queue.  In this manner, that Task will be considered
>   fairly along with all other work items queued globally.

Comment: Thanks, but see comment to myself- I'm linking to that same article.